# Proof by induction verfication

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

The question states that given $S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k^2+k)}$, define $S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k^2+k)}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

It then asks to prove by induction that $S(n) =\frac{n}{n+1}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

I've gone through the regular steps, letting $n=1$ and assuming true for $k$

But when I add the $(k+1)^{th}$ term to both sides to prove for $n=k+1$, I get a value instead of a general form.

So I need someone to verify the answer.

Comment: Can you show your working?

Comment: When proving n=k+1, I used 1/(k^2+k) + 1/(k+1)(k+2) = k/(k+1) + 1/(k+1)(k+2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac1{n^2+n}=\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\implies$$

$$\implies\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2+k}=\left(1-\frac12\right)+\left(\frac12-\frac13\right)+\ldots+\left(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n\right)=\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Try partial fraction decomposition on 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2+k}
$$

you will see it is a telescope sum.

Hope this helps :)